# main.c: warning: passing argument of ‘’ from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc

I'm trying to pass and return a two-dimension dynamic array by parameter, however it always shows this warning I mentioned in the question. I know there's something wrong with the array parameter, but I couldn't find in any book or a website how to properly pass an array whose dimensions change. I've read similar questions to mine about the warning and it's mostly about adding a `&` in your pointer, which I haven't added in mine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun(int m, int n, int (*arr)[n]);

int main(void) {
    int i, j, m, n, **arr;
    printf("Enter the dimensions m, n\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    arr = (int **)malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
    fun(m, n, *arr);
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%5d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (arr == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    } else
    if (arr != NULL) {
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}

void fun(int m, int n, int (*arr)[n]) {
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            k = k + 1;
            arr[i][j] = k;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see the warning you mention with `gcc 7.4.0` and command `gcc -Wall filename.c -o testfile`, so probably mentioning the compiler version etc might help ; `gcc` warns me, though, that you are passing `*arr` instead of `arr` : `fun()` apparently wants _a pointer to an array_, that is, `int **` -- and this is what you allocate ; but then it looks like you are passing an `int *`

Comment: `int (*arr)[n]` declares pointer to array of `n` size, you need `int **`.

Comment: Two general suggestions: (a) keep it simple and go with `int*`, `int**`, etc when needed. (b) avoid double pointers when using arrays ; instead, allocate flat chunks of memory ( unless they are _really_ big ) and do pointer arithmetic : `p[i*n+j] = value` style ; that might make your life slightly more simple and code easier to read

Comment: @ch3055: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 7):

```
int **arr;
```

In `main`, `arr` is a pointer to a pointer to integer and you populate it with a nested memory allocation, because there are two levels of pointers involved. The `arr[i]` can be fragmented and each could hold a different number of entries, making `arr` a "ragged" array.

```
int (*arr)[n]
```

The argument to your function is a pointer to an array of `n` integers. Here the entries of `arr` are contiguous in memory, so that `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are `sizeof(int[n])` bytes apart.

These are different types and the compiler tells you so. Pick one.

**A** You can stick with the pointer-to-pointer approach. Then your function signature must match the definition in `main`:

```
void fun(int m, int n, int **arr) ...
```

In that case, you must also `free` all `arr[i]` at the end, before `free(arr)`.

**B** Alternatively, you can keep your curret function and create a contiguous array with a single allocation:

```
int (*arr)[n] = malloc(m * sizeof(*arr));
```

Then pass it to your function directly without dereferencing it:

```
fun(m, n, arr);
```

At the end, just `free(arr)`.

Comment: Thank you! I had free(arr[i]) before but it was showing another warning and it was fixed by removing it. But int ** was the problem after all.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing pointer to int(that is *arr) but you have declared function that will get pointer to array of `n` integers.

So, just make the following changes:

```
void fun(int m, int n, int **arr); // also change where function definition begins
fun(m, n, arr);
```

By the way, freeing memory is incomplete.

```
for (i=0; i<m; i++)
  free(arr[i]); // first free individual array elements
free(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you! This and the other answers really helped.

Answer (score 1):

`fun` is defined as receiving a pointer to variable sized array or `n` `int`. This is a C99 specific syntax that some C compilers might not support. You could also have defined `fun` with a simpler and more readable prototype that is in fact equivalent:

```
void fun(int m, int n, int arr[m][n]);
```

Also equivalent to this one:

```
void fun(int m, int n, int arr[][n]);
```

The problem is you allocate a very different type of object: an array of `m` pointers to arrays of `n` `int`. You should instead allocate an array of `m` variable sized arrays of `n` `int` and store its address to a pointer with the appropriate type:

```
int (*arr)[n] = malloc(m * sizeof(*arr));
```

Or just define it as a 2D variable sized array with automatic storage:

```
int arr[m][n];
```

If allocated with `malloc()`, you would free the object with

```
free(arr);
```

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun(int m, int n, int arr[m][n]);

int main(void) {
    int i, j, m, n;

    printf("Enter the dimensions m, n\n");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &m, &n) != 2 || m <= 0 || n <= 0)
        return 1;

    int (*arr)[n] = malloc(m * sizeof(*arr));
    if (arr == NULL)
        return 1;

    fun(m, n, arr);

    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%5d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int m, int n, int arr[m][n]) {
    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            k = k + 1;
            arr[i][j] = k;
        }
    }
}
```